# How to put datetime condition in where clause on nvarchar column in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL server 2005 database, a table has a nvarchar column that contains either datetime or some string value. e.g. `03/11/2011 4:00:07 AM` or `Completed`.

```
 select * from log 
 where status >= 
    case isdate(status) 
    when 1 then convert(datetime, '03/11/2011 12:00:01 AM') 
    else '' 
    end 
and status <= 
    case isdate(status) 
    when 1 then convert(datetime, '03/11/2011 4:00:00 PM') 
    else '' 
end
```

I need data where status field has datetime and datetime is between date1 and date2.

Comment: @Jeff: You edited it. But what is SWL?

Comment: It's called a typo, User13839404. Feel free to fix it next time rather than comment.

Comment: I hope this isn't a query that needs to be efficient. It's not "SARGable" (see google) and the biggest problem is the ambiguous datatype for the column. Maybe that's ok in your context but if queries are slow, you need to normalize the content, preferably as a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE 
CASE WHEN ISDATE(status) = 1 
     THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,status) 
END BETWEEN '20110311 12:00:01' AND '20110418 16:00:00'
```